# How to copy file using Using Net::SSH2?

Tags: perl

Need help in copying $cmd output to second server via scp/sftp. I have this code; works fine but take long time as $ cmd output is ~700MB, 15000 lines.

```
use warnings;
use Net::SSH2;
my ($host, $user, $password, $outfile) = @ARGV;
my $cmd = "show zoneset active";
my $ssh = Net::SSH2->new();
$ssh->connect($host);
$ssh->auth_keyboard($user, $password);
my $channel = $ssh->channel();
$channel->exec($cmd);
open OUTPUT, ">", "$outfile";
while (<$channel>) { print  OUTPUT };
$channel->close;
$ssh->disconnect;
```

Comment: I don't know what connection you have, but for me sending 700MB (+ encryption) may take its time. Are you sure this *can* be speeded up?

Answer (score 0):

Given some assumptions:

1. The output of `show zoneset active` changes a bit, but not much, each time it's run
2. You want to run this command multiple times

Then your best bet might be to create the file on the remote server, and then use rsync (perhaps with `File::Rsync`) to fetch the file on top of an existing copy on your local server.

From `man rsync`:

> Rsync is a fast and extraordinarily versatile file copying tool. It can
>   copy locally, to/from another host over any remote shell, or to/from a
>   remote rsync daemon. It offers a large number of options that control
>   every aspect of its behavior and permit very flexible specification of the
>   set of files to be copied. It is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm,
>   which reduces the amount of data sent over the network by sending only the
>   differences between the source files and the existing files in the
>   destination. Rsync is widely used for backups and mirroring and as an
>   improved copy command for everyday use.